# Fastest way to build a 3D map from 3D Scans and TF data?

Tags: mapping, pcl, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I did some 3D scans and saved them to a bag file with the corresponding tf, imu and odom frames. But I am wondering how I can build a map of my data?

Is there something like a package where I just have to input the PointCloud2, imu and tf data?
Or do I have to code something in combination with the PCL library?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60725/fastest-way-to-build-a-3d-map-from-3d-scans-and-tf-data?/) by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 496 on 2013-04-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Define, what a 3D map is for you and what you expect from the algorithm.

I'm assuming from the topic you want mapping from known poses and not SLAM.
There are multiple valid representations. A quick and simple way would be to build an octomap using the [octomap_server](http://ros.org/wiki/octomap_server) package. This accepts localized (via tf) PointCloud2 and produces an octree map.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on 2013-04-15**:
Well, when I use an octomap, the movement of my robot is not recognized. That is the main problem. So the captured point clouds are interfering and my map is not "growing". Hope you understand my english... Maybe a solution is to transform a point cloud to a laser scan and do mapping with the scans.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-04-15**:
What kind of tf data do you have? tf needs to transform to a fixed frame to work for mapping. Otherwise you need a 3D SLAM approach or in the simplest case try if odometry works.

**Comment by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on 2013-04-17**:
We only have transforms on the robot itself and not to a static point. The odometry was recorded on another pc and has to be integrated.